# JQuery. Click on DIV, display menu. How?

Tags: jquery, html

I got a div that is floated right and onClick, I would like to display another DIV containing a list of items that can be clicked on which could also be assigned by id, their own click events. Like a drop down menu for example.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks promising: http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show one div when you click another?

```
$("#diva").on("click", function(){
  $("#divb").toggle();
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/uxaxap/edit#javascript,html

Comment: The position of the DIV to be display must always align to the bottom right of its parent. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @Vini That's a CSS question that would need to be asked after you close out this question. This may provide some direction: http://jsbin.com/uxaxap/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#diva ul li").click(function(){
  $(this).find('#div').slideToggle();
});
```